# Number of Antisymmetric Relations that are both Reflexive and Symmetric

Tags: combinatorics, relations

I came across this question that tells us to validate the following statement-

*For every non-empty finite set X, there exists a unique antisymmetric relation on X that is both reflexive and symmetric*

My validation-

Consider X={1,2,3}. Let R be a relation on X such that R={(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}.
This relation is clearly

- reflexive as (x, x) ∈ R ∀ x ∈ X
- symmetric as (x, x) ∈ R ⇒ (x, x) ∈ R
- antisymmetric as (x,y)∈R ∧ (y,x)∉R, unless x=y

My doubt is just by using this example is my deduction right that a purely reflexive relation is the only antisymmetric relation possible on X that is both reflexive as well as symmetric

Comment: You may not prove generic statements about generic $X$ by picking a single specific $X$ to look at in greater detail.  You showed the existence of an $R$ for that single instance of $X$.  You have not shown that this was the *only* $R$ that works for that $X$.  You have not yet shown the existence or uniqueness of any such $R$ for the infinitely many other choices for $X$.  Your proof should have been generic without making any explicit reference to the contents of $X$.

Comment: That said, you should have hopefully at least spotted a pattern, that any symmetric, antisymmetric, reflexive relation will necessarily be the "*identity relation*" or "*identity function*" over $X$.  You should prove that *regardless* the set $X$ that the identity relation will be a subset of any symmetric, antisymmetric, reflexive relation.  Further you should prove that any symmetric, antisymmetric, reflexive relation over $X$ must be a subset of the identity relation.  See if you can finish the proof and explain why this proves existence and uniqueness as well.